# on some Samsung devices decoding H264 stream at hight resolution with MediaCodec, dequeueOutputBuffer always return -1

Tags: android, h.264, android-mediacodec

I am trying to use the MediaCodec API to decoding H264 stream with Android client. 
sample code:

```
int decoderStatus = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(mBufferInfo, TIMEOUT_USEC);
```

When the remote H264 stream resolution size is bigger (eg: 1600*1200), this function will always return `-1(MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER)`, so the decode will failed but can not catch any exception. if the resolution is lower (eg 1920*1080, 1280*720), the decode machanism works OK.

this only happens on some Samsung devices: Galaxy S3, Note2, and note.

I also check these machines that supported H264 profile Level, and they are all Level 4 devices and can support maximum resolution size 2048*1024 theoretically (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC#Levels).

Does someone meet this problem? I try to modify the parameters when `queueInputBuffer` and `dequeueOutputBuffer` but failed to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

this reason is due to the Samsung devices which use the EXYNOS4412/EXYNOS4210 processor. these type of processor use the Mali-400 MP4 GPU.

The SoC integrates an ARM Mali-400 MP4 GPU (15.8 GFLOPS at 440 MHz). Typical smartphone games (2012) will run fluently even in high resolutions like 1280 x 720 pixels. Videos can be accelerated by a multi-format video decoder (1080p AVI, WMV, H.264, H.263, VC1, MPEG2, MPEG4).
(http://www.notebookcheck.net/Samsung-Exynos-4412-Quad-ARM-SoC.86876.0.html)

So if the video resolution exceed 1080P the decoder will become frozen.